# opencv cv::max behavior unexpected

Tags: c++, opencv, max, mat

I'm using `cv::max` with an uninitialized `Mat` object, and error happens when passing the uninitialized object as the 1st param:

```
Mat a=Mat::ones(2,3, CV_32S);
Mat b;
max(a, b); // 1. OK
max(b, a); // 2. OpenCV Error
```

The error message is:

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is
>   neither 'a rray op array' (where arrays have the same size and type),
>   nor 'array op scalar' , nor 'scalar op array') in cv::binary_op, file
>   C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc
>   11-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 1021

**My question**: Should not the two calls be of the same effect *theorectically*? Is that a implementation imperfection or my misunderstanding?

### EDIT:

I'm using vs2012 with OpenCV2.4.8 x86 on win7 x64

Comment: most amazing to me is, that the 1st one does *not* crash

Comment: Could you specify which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: @YuchenZhong It's opencv2.4.8, vs2012. See my edit plz ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen , make an [issue here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) ?

Comment: @berak, I made an issue here: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3696, hope someone would notice that...

Comment: yep. good. at least you reach the devs there. (here, not so..)

Comment: Running it on my computer it seems to work and no errors/warnings are displayed. I do not know what could be the problem in your case. I am using OpenCV 2.4.8 x64 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon do you mean the 2nd case `max(b, a);` doesn't raise an error?

Comment: yes, and I have tried `cv::max(b, a)` and also without it and `using namespace cv;`. It run, no errors, no warnings, no crashes

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug, but has now been fixed. Please see http://code.opencv.org/issues/3696#note-7 for comment stating that the bug has been fixed.

Note: An equivalent problem existed for `cv::min`.

Comment: well, I see... I opened that issue there ;)